# Is there a model which can interact directly with a database and GridView

Tags: c#, xaml, sqlite, uwp

I have a GridView. I want to set the data template to bind to row of my database(my SQLite database to be specific). The database **will** be updated at run time. I want the GridView to update itself. But the database is too large to be stored in an Observable Collection.

I have had little experience in Qt. And there was an SqlTableModel. Is there anything of such sort in uwp or I have to implement it on my own?

Answer (score 1):

I will give you all in one solution for any **Enterprise database** connection with uwp app with full efficiency and editing option as well. you should use **DataGrid** control of **windows community toolkit**. learn more about it here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/datagrid

Comment: I don't know how and why this thing is not a part of the official SDK. Turns out, it is exactly what I need. I am implementing this before I mark it as the correct answer. But I will before tomorrow

Comment: One more thing, the question is still the same. Is there a model can interact directly with my database and which I can bind my DataGrid or I have to implement that Model on my own

Comment: I think you need to create a helper class with static methods which talks to your database context and handles all kind of CRUD operations, then using methods in that helper class you can use them in your ViewModel where everything happens with connection to the UI. so the short answer is "yeah you have to implement that on your own but if you use Entity framework over your sqlite database that will make it a lot simpler for you instead of talking to sqlite directly. @Hemil